# How should a typical .yml or .xml matrix look for OpenCV use

Tags: opencv

I need to specify a matrix inside a file and then load it onto OpenCV as a `Mat` for further processing. How can the cols and lines be specified and where do elements go within the *.xml* or *.yml* file?, (for example element `A(i,j)` for i from 1 to m lines and for j from 1 to n cols.
In Matlab for example, this is done by loading a *.dat* file with just the numbers. What is confusing with OpenCV is that the *.yml* or *.xml* have some other scripts to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read/Write any OpenCV data structure to or from *.xml* / *.yaml* file is very simple.

Before you write any content to such file you need to open it and at the end to close it. The XML/YAML data structure in OpenCV is `FileStorage`.

```
string filename = "I.xml";
FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::WRITE);

Mat R = Mat_<uchar >::eye (3, 3),

fs << "R" << R; // Write entire cv::Mat
fs["R"] >> R;   // Read entire cv::Mat
```

Check out this link [File Input and Output using XML and YAML files](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/file_input_output_with_xml_yml/file_input_output_with_xml_yml.html)