# How to use clustering file after training

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, svm

I trained the data using BOG with SVM , i trained it , now i just want to open it through `xml` , i don't want to train it again and again on every run ,
I trained the svm and now loading it using its loading function

```
CvSVM svm;
svm.load( "trainsvm.xml" );
```

But how to do the same with vocabulary file which i use for clustering using BOG algorithm , below is my code , which is training the data , but i want to open it now like `svm`

```
for (i = all_names.begin(); i != all_names.end(); ++i)
{
    Dir=( (count < files.size() ) ? YourImagesDirectory : YourImagesDirectory_2);

    Mat row_img = cv::imread( Dir +*i, 0 );

    detector.detect( row_img, keypoints);

    RetainBestKeypoints(keypoints, 20);

    extractor->compute( row_img, keypoints, descriptors_1);

    descriptors_1.reshape(1,1);

    bow.add(descriptors_1);

    ++count;
}

vector<string>::const_iterator k;

cout<<"CLUSTERING"<<endl;
Mat vocabulary = bow.cluster();

dextract.setVocabulary(vocabulary);

cv::Mat training_mat(num_img , dictionarySize,CV_32FC1);
cv::Mat labels(num_img,1,CV_32FC1);
```

This is clustering the data , now i don't want to run it again and again because it takes too much time , when it trained once , i just want to use it , so that i can speed up my program

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify this question as 'How to save a custom Mat object, which is not an image?'.

You can use cv::FileStorage. You can follow this documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#filestorage) and this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312904/how-to-write-a-float-mat-to-a-file-in-opencv).

Comment: I know about FileStorage , but this is technique is not usefull for my question , vocabulary is not storing in it for using it with svm , and i need a full explain answer for it

Comment: Mat vocabulary = bow.cluster(); from this line of code it seems your vocabulary is an instance of Mat object, hence it can be written to disk using FileStorage. Maybe you should explain your question more detailed and tell why this technique is not useful for your question.

Comment: You want to deliver something like this `FileStorage fs; fs.open("Vocalbury.xml", FileStorage::WRITE); Mat vocabulary = bow.cluster(); fs["Vocalbury"]>>vocabulary ; dextract.setVocabulary(vocabulary); Mat training_mat(num_img , dictionarySize,CV_32FC1); Mat labels(num_img,1,CV_32FC1);`

Comment: `cv::FileStorage file("vocabulary.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
cv::Mat vocabularyToSave = bow.cluster(); 
file.open();
file << vocabularyToSave;

cv::FileStorage file2("vocabulary.xml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
cv::Mat vocabularyToRead;
file2.open();
vocabularyToRead << file2;;
 
dextract.setVocabulary(vocabularyToRead); 
cv::Mat training_mat(num_img , dictionarySize,CV_32FC1); 
cv::Mat labels(num_img,1,CV_32FC1);`

Comment: +1 , but as this question is bounty you need to resolve it fully :) ,  error is here `vocabularyToRead << file2;` in using `<<`

Comment: Currently I don't have much time to implement it, but if I do, I'll write it to here. The things that I wrote were just my thoughts..

Comment: is it okay to use `file.open("vocabulary.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);` this or we must need to use `encoding`

Comment: I didn't get the question. What do you mean by encoding?

Comment: encoding mean utf-8 or 16 like its given in the syntax of it