# How to read the text file and create Mat object in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

Hi i  have being able to write a Mat object in to a text file. As follows,

```
std::fstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open( "myFile.txt", std::ios::out ) ;

    outputFile << des_object.rows << std::endl;
    outputFile << des_object.cols << std::endl;

    for(int i=0; i<des_object.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<des_object.cols; j++)
        {
            outputFile << des_object.at<float>(i,j) << std::endl;
        }

    }
    outputFile.close( );
```

In my code in the first 2 lines im printing the row count and the column count to use when im reading it back.
But im unable to read the text file and create the Mat Object again.

The following is the code i tried. Not sure whether my code is correct.

```
Mat des_object1;
    std::ifstream file("myFile.txt");
    std::string str; 
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int a = 0;
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        if(a == 0){
            rows = std::stoi( str );
        }else if(a == 1){
            cols = std::stoi( str );
        }else{

            for(i; i< rows; i++)
            {
                for(j; j<cols; j++)
                {
                     des_object1.at<float>(i,j) = ::atof(str.c_str());
                     break;
                }
            }

        }
        ++a;
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

it's probably far easier, to use the opencv [FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#filestorage-filestorage):

```
// write:
Mat m;
FileStorage fs("myfile.txt",FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "mat1" << m;

// read:
FileStorage fs("myfile.txt",FileStorage::READ);
fs["mat1"] >> m;
```

Comment: This work when i write the mat in to the file. But when i read it give me an empty one

Comment: @berak, the link that you provided mentions that FileStorage works for xml/yaml files, nothing mentioned about .txt files. I tried reading a .txt file but it gave me an error: Parsing error: Valid xml should start with '<?xml ...?>'> in icvXMLParse.................

Comment: This actually works on txt files. Try `imread`ing something into `m` and use the code to write it to `myfile.txt`. Take a look at the output if you're interested. Then read it back to `m` by the provided reading code and save it with `imwrite`; you'll see it's saved and the image is viewable

Answer (score 0):

You got your inner loops in the wrong location: You'd need to keep the counter around for each iteration reading a line. It can be done a lot simpler, though:

```
if (in >> rows >> cols) {
    // resize the matrix to its proper size
    for (int r(0); r!= rows; ++r) {
        for (int c(0); c != cols; ++c) {
            if (!(in >> mat[r][c])) {
                throw std:: runtime_error("failed to read matrix");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

initialize these two outside the `while` loop

```
int k=0;
int l=0;
```

and instead of using the `for` loop

```
if(j<cols){
    des_object1.at<float>(k,l) = ::atof(str.c_str());
}else{
    k=0;
    l++;
    des_object1.at<float>(k,l) = ::atof(str.c_str());
}
j++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method for reading a `Mat` from an `.asc` that should work for `.txt` too.

Maybe there are more stylish and efficient ways to do that, but this method works and is easy to understand.

**Head**

```
int Load_From_Path_Text(Mat *pMA_Out, string path)
```

**Variables**

```
ifstream        IS_File;
string          ST_Line;
stringstream    SS_Line;
unsigned int    rows        = 0;
unsigned int    cols        = 0;
unsigned int    y           = 0;
unsigned int    x           = 0;
float           F_Value;
```

**Get Size**

```
IS_File.open(path);
while(getline(IS_File, ST_Line))
{
    if(cols == 0)
    {
        SS_Line << ST_Line;
        while(SS_Line >> F_Value)
            cols++;
    }

    rows++;
}
IS_File.close();
```

**Create Image**

```
*pMA_Out = Mat(rows, cols, CV_32FC1);
```

**Read Data**

```
IS_File.open(path);
while(getline(IS_File, ST_Line))
{
    SS_Line.clear();
    SS_Line << ST_Line;
    x = 0;

    while(SS_Line >> F_Value)
    {
        pMA_Out->at<float>(y, x) = F_Value;
        x++;
    }

    y++;
}
IS_File.close();
```

**Example**

```
1 1 1 -2
1 2 1 0.5
1 1 3 2.1
1 1 1 1.5
```

turns to
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhrly.jpg)
(after beeing converted to `CV_8UC1` using `normalize` with `CV_MINMAX` to be displayed).