# Efficiently load a large Mat into memory in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, opencv3.0

Is there a more efficient way to load a large Mat object into memory than the FileStorage method in OpenCV?

I have a large Mat with 192 columns and 1 million rows I want to store locally in a file and load into memory then my application starts. There is no problem using the FileStorage, but I was wondering if there exists a more efficient method to do this. At the moment it takes about 5 minutes to load the Mat into memory using the Debug mode in Visual Studio and around 3 minutes in the Release mode and the size of the data file is around 1.2GB.

Is the FileStorage method the only method available to do this task?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*Are you ok with a **100x** speedup?*

---

You should save and load your images in binary format. You can do that with the `matwrite` and `matread` function in the code below.

I tested both loading from a `FileStorage` and the binary file, and for a smaller image with 250K rows, 192 columns, type `CV_8UC1` I got these results (time in ms):

```
// Mat: 250K rows, 192 cols, type CV_8UC1
Using FileStorage: 5523.45
Using Raw:         50.0879
```

On a image with 1M rows and 192 cols using the binary mode I got (time in ms):

```
// Mat: 1M rows, 192 cols, type CV_8UC1
Using FileStorage: (can't load, out of memory)
Using Raw:         197.381
```

**NOTE**

1. Never measure performance in *debug*.
2. 3 minutes to load a matrix seems way too much, even for `FileStorage`s. However, you'll gain a lot switching to binary mode.

Here the code with the functions `matwrite` and `matread`, and the test:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


void matwrite(const string& filename, const Mat& mat)
{
    ofstream fs(filename, fstream::binary);

    // Header
    int type = mat.type();
    int channels = mat.channels();
    fs.write((char*)&mat.rows, sizeof(int));    // rows
    fs.write((char*)&mat.cols, sizeof(int));    // cols
    fs.write((char*)&type, sizeof(int));        // type
    fs.write((char*)&channels, sizeof(int));    // channels

    // Data
    if (mat.isContinuous())
    {
        fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(0), (mat.dataend - mat.datastart));
    }
    else
    {
        int rowsz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * mat.cols;
        for (int r = 0; r < mat.rows; ++r)
        {
            fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(r), rowsz);
        }
    }
}

Mat matread(const string& filename)
{
    ifstream fs(filename, fstream::binary);

    // Header
    int rows, cols, type, channels;
    fs.read((char*)&rows, sizeof(int));         // rows
    fs.read((char*)&cols, sizeof(int));         // cols
    fs.read((char*)&type, sizeof(int));         // type
    fs.read((char*)&channels, sizeof(int));     // channels

    // Data
    Mat mat(rows, cols, type);
    fs.read((char*)mat.data, CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * rows * cols);

    return mat;
}

int main()
{
    // Save the random generated data
    {
        Mat m(1024*256, 192, CV_8UC1);
        randu(m, 0, 1000);

        FileStorage fs("fs.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
        fs << "m" << m;

        matwrite("raw.bin", m);
    }

    // Load the saved matrix

    {
        // Method 1: using FileStorage
        double tic = double(getTickCount());

        FileStorage fs("fs.yml", FileStorage::READ);
        Mat m1;
        fs["m"] >> m1;

        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
        cout << "Using FileStorage: " << toc << endl; 
    }

    {
        // Method 2: usign raw binary data
        double tic = double(getTickCount());

        Mat m2 = matread("raw.bin");

        double toc = (double(getTickCount()) - tic) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
        cout << "Using Raw: " << toc << endl;
    }

    int dummy;
    cin >> dummy;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the use of storing the output of channels? you don't seem to use it when reading back the file. Only asking because I am having some trouble with a similar function of my own

Comment: @sturkmen 1) I have production code with this version, and I don't want to brake it 2) the channel information can be useful for loading the image in, say, matlab 3) saving one byte it's not a big deal 4) it's pretty easy to update the code without channels ;)

Comment: Is that possible to use this method for recording purpose? I mean instead of using cv::VideoWriter, it might be very efficient if we could adopt this approach!