# Unable to write images using imwrite in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to write to an image using imwrite as follows:

```
Mat object = imread ("C:/Users/User/Desktop/book.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
//calculate integral image
        Mat iObject;
        integral(object, iObject);
        imshow("Good Matches", iObject);
        imwrite("C:/Users/User/Desktop/IntegralImage.jpg", iObject);
        cvWaitKey(0);
```

but it does not suceed, I read about it, some solutions was to change jpg to bmp. I tried it also but no result! Any help please

Comment: Does it appear correctly when you do imshow? Are you using the account "User" and do you have access to write to "User"'s Desktop

Comment: yes imshow appear correctly.. How can I know if I have access to write?

Comment: does it give any error message?

Comment: No it does not give any error :(

Comment: What's the problem? You can't save the image, or the image is saved but it's basically all white?

Comment: Also check the `bool` return value of `imwrite`

Comment: I can't save the image at all

Comment: how to check the bool of imwrite?

Comment: `bool ok = imwrite(...); if(!ok) {//error}`. Next time please use @name to notify. However, I can't reproduce your problem. Try starting Visual Studio or whatever IDE you're using as administrator, and retry. This will show if it's a permission problem

Comment: @Miki it works Thanks :) Actually I has 2 images to save, One is saved successfully , The second is saved blank..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93719/discussion-between-user3552658-and-miki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cannot save image**

This is because you don't have the privileges to write in that location. Solutions:

1. Start your program as administrator
2. Change to a location where you have enough privileges

---

**Integral image is saved *blank***

The integral image is of type `CV_32UC1`, so values higher than 255 will be saturated to 255, and saved as *white*. You can't recover original values from the saved image.

Solutions:

1. Normalize the values to fit the range `[0,255]`, and save the `CV_8U` image. You can't recover original values from the saved image, but at least is scaled and shown correctly.
2. Use `FileStorage` to save the original data. You keep the original values.
3. If you need more speed that `FileStorage`, you can save raw binary data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845) for an example. You keep the original values.

This is a sample code to show solutions 1 and 2. For 3 please refer to the given link.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat1b object = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Calculate integral image
    Mat1i iObject;
    integral(object, iObject);

    imwrite("save_1i.png", iObject);

    // the saved image has saturated values

    // /////////////////////////////////////////

    // Save using imwrite
    Mat1b save_1b;
    normalize(iObject, save_1b, 255, 0, NORM_MINMAX);
    imwrite("save_1b.png", save_1b);

    // the saved image has scaled values, but displayed correctly


    // /////////////////////////////////////////

    // Save using FileStorage
    {
        FileStorage fs("save_fs.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
        fs << "integral" << iObject;

        // the saved file has original values
    }


    // Load using FileStorage
    Mat1i loadedIObject;
    {
        FileStorage fs("save_fs.yml", FileStorage::READ);
        fs["integral"] >> loadedIObject;
    }

    // loadedIObject has original values

    return 0;
}
```