# What is the best way to transfer a cv::Mat object between different processes?

Tags: c++, opencv, pipe, named-pipes

I am trying to pass couple of cv::Mat object from one program to another, both implemented in C++ and preferably run in parallel. The cv::Mat does not have an image in it, so imread and imwrite are not useful here (we can not compress data with traditional image compressing methods). One solution would be writing the matrix in a file (CSV file for example), but since the program process too much information, the disk will be the bottleneck, besides, I soon will run out of disk space.

After some digging, I found pipes (name or unnamed) as a useful solution. I wrote two pilot programs: 
Producer.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{       
        Mat image;
        image = imread(argv[1]);
        cout << image;
        cout.flush();
        return 0;
}
```

Consumer.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{       
        Mat image;
        cin >> image;
        imshow("Image", image);
        waitKey();
        return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, the second program will not compile.

> mismatched types ‘_CharT2*’ and ‘cv::Mat’
>     cin >> image;

Which means (I guess) ">>" operator is not overloaded for cv::Mat. Even though we might be able to override the >> operator, since the matrix is big, and stdin and stdout are text based, it would not be the best neither the easiest way.

So, back to main question: What is the best way of passing a cv::Mat object (or potentially any other binary object) from one program to another?

Comment: TCP/IP But this question can be answered in more than one way

Comment: You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845) how to serialize and deserialize a `Mat`

Comment: Thanks GPPK for the answer, TCP/IP is a good choice but how and why they are better than pipes?

Comment: Thanks Miki for your response. The proposed solution was inspiring, even though based on my tests the speed boos, is something between 5 and 10 times faster (I believe it relates to system which runs the test). I'm going to mix that with named pipes which hopefully will solve my problem. I will post the solution soon after I finished it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mat (or any other object) should be serialized in some way. The easy way of serializing in opencv is using FileStorage. Here is the sample codes:

producer:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1]);
    FileStorage fs("temp", FileStorage::WRITE);
    fs << "MyImage" << image;
    return 0;
}
```

consumer:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat image;
    FileStorage fs("temp", FileStorage::READ);
    fs["MyImage"] >> image;
    imshow("Image", image);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Where "temp" is the file name in which the data will be stored. The best way to run these programs in parallel without using fileSystem, is to define a named pipe "temp", in the proper place, before running programs in parallel:

```
>mkfifo temp
>./producer testFile.jpg | ./consumer
```

This way no disk is used and the programs can be run in parallel.

The fileStorage changes the binary content of Mat to ascii, which is time consuming. One may decide to serialize the content in binary as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845) and use the named pipes with them.

Comment: I have tried float type variable with FileStorage; it also works. But is it possible to send & receive the variable on-fly? I mean real-time sending & receiving during the operation.

Comment: Yes, fifos are an excellent solution to send/receive data on the fly, but sometimes, you might need process synchronization. The simple examples above run in parallel and consumer consumes data as it becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

Write the file to disk, and remember to delete it as soon as you're done with it. The file cache will delay a physical write, and the rapid deletion the prevents the physical write.

Alternatively, store the data is shared memory.

Comment: Writing to disk is not in my options. I'm afraid the file cache is much smaller than my data (I  might have as big as 4GB data), in this case pipes are much better.

Comment: @PejmanHabashi: Usuallu cheaper to buy some extra memory than to come up with a  complex workaround. Still, try shared memory.

Comment: @MSaltersL thanks for pointing it out. The disk space it not a big deal, I have plenty of it, and 10GB memory. Speed is more important here, disks are too lazy compared to RAM.

Comment: What disk speed? With sufficient RAM, files stay in cache.

Comment: I got your point, but what is the benefit of files over named pipes?

Comment: Portable, easier to create from within your program.