# Read value of pixel in a image and save on file OpenCv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, mat

i using a code to read an image ( colour or grayscale ) ,convert that in grayscale if it is coloured, read every single pixel and after that save on txt file But i have a problem.
When i run the program, it return me this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3737
```

Where is the problem?
i post code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat colorImage = imread("aust.jpg");

    // First convert the image to grayscale.
    Mat grayImage;
    cvtColor(colorImage, grayImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    // Then apply thresholding to make it binary.
    Mat binaryImage(grayImage.size(), grayImage.type());


    // Open the file in write mode.
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("Myfiles.txt");

    // Iterate through pixels.
    for (int r = 0; r < grayImage.rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < grayImage.cols; c++)
        {
            int pixel = grayImage.at<uchar>(r, c);

            outputFile << pixel << " ";
        }
        outputFile << "-1 ";
    }

    // Close the file.
    outputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

i try to read an image like this:

[image]

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply load the image directly as grayscale, so you do not need to do the conversion manually:

```
Mat grayImage = imread("aust.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

If you want to read as color image and then convert to grayscale, you should call `cv::imread` with the `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` flag.

---

btw, the line below the comment

```
// Then apply thresholding to make it binary.
```

does not apply thresholding. I guess you intended to use `cv::threshold`.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the input image to `cvtColor` is not a 3 or 4 channel image. Please check the number of channels:

```
colorImage.channels();
```

Also note that you should use `COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, and not `COLOR_RGB2GRAY`. The default order in OpenCV is BGR, and not RGB.

`COLOR_XXX2YYY` is the new name, as well as `IMREAD_XXX` used later.

---

As already mentioned, you can load the image directly as grayscale, with:

```
Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

---

To store data in *csv* format, you can use `cv::format` function:

```
Mat1b gray;
cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

ofstream out("Myfiles.txt");
out << cv::format(gray, "csv");
```

Or you can use [FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#filestorage), or [save the binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845).