# Change data of OpenCV matrix from pointer

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, computer-vision

I am trying to capture images from several cameras using the cameras driver,OpenCV and C++. My goal is to get as many FPS as possible, and to this end I have found saving the images in the hard drive to be the slowest operation. In order to speed up the process, I am doing each saving in separate threads. Problem is, I still have to wait for the saving to be complete to avoid the captured image being overwritten. Doing this provides good results, but for unknown reasons every 30-40 frames the speed is 10x higher.

I am addressing this by creating a ring buffer where I store the images, as these sudden drops in write speed are very short. I have obtained very good results using this approach, but unfortunately for more than 3 cameras the camera driver can't handle the stress and my program halts, waiting for the first image of the 4th camera to be saved. I checked and it's not the CPU, as 3 cameras + a thread writing random data in the disk works fine.

Now, seeing how using opencv reduced the stress on the camera driver, I would like to create a OpenCV mat buffer to hold the images while they are saved without my camera overwritting them (well, not until the buffer has done a whole lap, which I will make sure won't happen).

I know I can do

```
cv::Mat colorFrame(cv::Size(width, height),CV_8UC3,pointerToMemoryOfCamera);
```

to **initialize** a frame from the memory written by the camera. This does not solve my problem, as it will only point to the data, and the moment the camera overwrites it, it will corrupt the image saved.

How do I create a matrix with a given size and type, and then copy the contents of the memory to this matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a *deep copy*. You can use [`clone`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ad1c9cc37d66c4e5bd05fae36f62d1cb4):

```
cv::Mat colorFrame = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3, pointerToMemoryOfCamera).clone();
```

---

You can also speed up the process of saving the images using [`matwrite` and `matread` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast response man, I was already leaving the office, thinking it would take more time for someone to answer! 

Will definitely try both tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: It worked flawlessly! The matwrite was slower than cv::imwrite, but I am now saving at a good frame rate without overlapping OR stalling. Thanks man!