# OpenCV FileStorage file size seems too large

Tags: opencv

I'm using `cv::FileStorage` to save a float image to hard drive before

```
cv::FileStorage file(out_path, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
file << "bla" << img;
```

This image at the point of saving is a `cv::Mat` of size 7716*5364 and data type 6, which should be `CV_64F`. In memory this should take up about 331 megabytes, but when I save this matrix the YAML file takes up about 1.2 gigabytes on the hard drive. Does each value contain that much overhead? I was hoping for FileStorage to do something like numpy.save, where such an array when I save it indeed takes up about 331 megabytes on the hard disk.

Comment: YAML is ASCII text - it's not efficient. I haven't tried but you should be able to write a 64-bit floating point TIFF, with compression even if disk space is an issue.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845)

Comment: @Miki thanks! I tried it but on compilation I get this error: `undefined reference to CR::matwrite(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::Mat const&)'`

Comment: I retract my statement above concerning 64-bit floating point TIFF - it seems at v3.4.3 of OpenCV it simply writes an 8-bit TIFF with no warning if passed a 64-bit float.

Comment: @Miki I tried out your 64-bit binary saving code, and wanted to let you know you can actually read it back and turn it into a viewable JPEG using **ImageMagick** at the command-line like this `magick -depth 64 -define quantum:format=floating-point -size 5364x7716+16 gray:image.bin -evaluate divide 100 result.jpg` Pretty neat as it means your format is somewhat *portable*! The `+16` skips the 16-bytes of rows, columns, type and mode that you have at the start.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah, that was what I read--32bit seems to be the maximum for `imwrite()`. And that's apparently for three colour channels. I couldn't get Miki's code to work so far, for writing, the first answer here worked well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312904/how-to-write-a-float-mat-to-a-file-in-opencv
I don't know yet how to read it back into a `cv::Mat` though.

Comment: @speed you probably need to put the functions declaration in a header file, or forward declare the functions. Hard to tell without seeing the code you're using.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Nice! Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Try clicking `edit` under your question and adding the simplest possible example using Miki’s code so we can take a look.