# How to save opencv Mat matrix to a file that can be loaded in Matlab

Tags: opencv

I want to check the details of some Mat matrices in my `OpenCV` Codes (within `Qt`). An easy way, to my knowledge, to check the data matrix is to load it in `Matlab`. So, I want to save these data into a file that can be loaded in `Matlab`. Anyone has the experience to do so? A concrete example will be greatly helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV provides a straightforward [example here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/db/d64/tutorial_load_save_image.html) using imwrite.  And Matlab can then open the jpg files with [imread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html).

Comment: Using imwrite may not save the data as they are. Some negative values be reset to zero or larger values truncated due to the range of image type?

Comment: You can always [normalize](https://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) as needed.

Comment: But what I need is to check the original data generated during running opencv codes? Is there better way to do that?

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312904/how-to-write-a-float-mat-to-a-file-in-opencv) out.

Answer (score 1):

The opencv Mat file can be saved to a csv file using `cv::format()` ([writeCSV](https://gist.github.com/zhou-chao/7a7de79de47c652196f1)), which can be read in Matlab using `csvread.m`.